# No Usar iframe dentro de php

Tags: php, iframe

Buenas tengo una duda como puedo obtener `//webblabla.com/index.html?sso=<?php echo $Auth; ?>` sin necesidad de usar iframe ?

Intente de esta manera pero sin exito:

```
<iframe 
   src="//webblabla.com/index.html?sso=<?php echo $Auth; ?>" 
   style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;"
>
</iframe>


<?phpecho file_get_contents("linkbobba?sso=".$Auth);?>
<?=include("bobba/index.html?sso=".$Auth)?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Con PHP

Es fácil de hacer esto con PHP, con un simple `file_get_contetns`

```php
print file_get_contetns("//webblabla.com/index.html?sso");
```

Esto imprimirá el contenido de una página (Regresa el HTML mas no podrás obtener el PHP de dicha página por motivos de seguridad) si quieres guardarlo en una variable puedes asignarlo

---

### Con Javascript

Puedes usar una petición AJAX de una manera muy sencilla

```javascript
fetch("//webblabla.com/index.html?sso").then(response => {
    response.text().then(resp => {
        // Resp es el contenido de la página
    });
}};
```

### Explicación

`fetch` es un método de JavaScript para hacer llamadas AJAX, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```javascript
fetch("url", {
    method:"GET"
}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => console.log(resp)).cath(err=>console.log(err));
```

`.then()` es el método para deducir si la petición fue exitosa y `.catch()` es el método para deducir si la petición tuvo algún error

Compatibilidad: `fetch()` es compatible con **TODOS** los navegadores

**AJAX Antes de `EcmaScript 6`**

Antes de `ES6`, se usaban las `XMLHttpRequest` (Siguen estando disponibles de uso, pero menos usadas) y tienen la siguiente forma

```javascript
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "url"); // Método, URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // Petición exitosa
        } else {
            console.log("Error en la petición AJAX");
        }
    }
}
xhr.send("someInfo=abc&abc=bcd");
```

En `xhr.send()` enviamos la información de la petición al servidor, envía la información como parámetros de URL sin importar si utilizas POST.

Comment: La `n` se movió de lugar en `file_get_contetns`, en ambos casos va antes de la `t`. Por el parámetro `$Auth`, me parece que la petición debería ser con `cURL` para enviar encabezados y que sea "identificada" como desde un navegador, además de posibles credenciales. ¡Buena respuesta!